# How do you analytically bound $f(x)=-2cos(2x)+4cos(x)-3$ to get $0$ for upper bound?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, upper-lower-bounds

How do you analytically bound $f(x)=-2\cos(2x)+4\cos(x)-3$ to get 0 for upper bound?

If you graph $f(x)$ it looks like:

[image]

Clearly from this graph we can see $-9 \leq f(x) \leq 0 $.

But how do you conclude this analytically?

My thinking is

$-2 \leq -2\cos(2x) \leq 2$ and $-4 \leq 4\cos(x) \leq 4 \implies  -6 \leq 2\cos(2x)+4\cos(x) \leq 6 $ .

Then subtracting by 3 across the inequality, it becomes

$$-9 \leq -2\cos(2x)+4\cos(x)-3 \leq 3 $$

While the upper bound of 3 is technically correct, the graph shows a tighter upper bound at 0.  Why can't I derive that tight upper bound to be 0 analytically? Is there a better way?

Comment: Use $$\cos2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1.$$

Comment: Your graph at x=0 has value -1, doesn't match your function (-3)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let 
$$f(x) = 2 \cos 2x + 4 \cos x - 3 = 2 (2 \cos^2 x - 1) + 4 \cos x - 3 = 4 \cos^2 x + 4 \cos x - 5.$$  So as a quadratic in $z = \cos x$, we have $$f(x) = 4z^2 + 4z - 5 = 4z^2 + 4z + 1 - 6 = (2z + 1)^2 - 6.$$  It follows that on the interval $z \in [-1,1]$, the maximum is attained when $(2z+1)^2$ is as large as possible, which occurs when $z = 1$, and the value attained is $3$.  The plot you have provided does not match the function you specified.  Clearly, when $x = 0$, we have $\cos 2x = \cos x = 1$, hence $$f(0) = 2 + 4 - 3 = 3.$$

---

After seeing the comments, if we consider instead the function $$g(x) = -2 \cos 2x + 4 \cos x - 3 = -4 \cos^2 x + 4 \cos x - 1 = -(2 \cos x - 1)^2,$$ it becomes immediately obvious that $g$ is at most $0$.